# get-spweb how can i get today created items

Tags: powershell, sharepoint, scripting

I'm using the next Powershell Script to get items from Sharepoint List and export it 
how can i edit this script to get only today created data or the data entered today 
This is the code

```
$MyWeb = Get-SPWeb "http://ilike-eg.suz.itcgr.net/SM"
$MyList = $MyWeb.Lists["SCGC"] 
$exportlist = @()

$Mylist.Items |  ForEach-Object {
$obj =   New-Object PSObject -property @{ 
        "A"="   "+$_["AACCOUNT_ID"]
        "B"="   "+$_["BTRANSACTION_ID"]
        "C"="          "+$_["CDATE"] 
        "D"="      "+$_["DCUSTOMER_ID"]
        "E"="     "+$_["ECUSTOMER_NAME"]
        "F"=" "+$_["FAMOUNT"]
        "G"=" "+$_["GCLASS"] 
}

#Remove unnecessary sort
$exportlist += $obj   
$DateStamp = get-date -uformat "%Y-%m-%d@%H-%M-%S"
$NameOnly = "CDP" 

#Exporting with sorted properties
$exportlist |
Select-Object A,B,C,D,E,F,G |
Export-Csv -Delimiter "`t"-path "$NameOnly.txt"
}

#Removed duplicate get-content line
$a, ${d:CDP.txt} = Get-Content .\CDP.txt
$a, ${d:CDP.txt} = Get-Content .\CDP.txt

(Get-Content D:\CDP.txt) |
Foreach-Object {$_ -replace $([char]34) -replace "`t" -replace '/', '-'} |
Set-Content D:\CDP.txt
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Where you're piping in the SPListItems, insert a query to get items created today

Change this:

```
$Mylist.Items |
```

To this:

```
$Mylist.Items | where {$_['Created'] -eq Get-Date -format d}
```

Comment: Can i replace (-q) by something act as (contain) because the items are being created and recorded on -u date format mm-dd-yyyy hh:mm:ss and Get-Date are getting mm-dd-yyyy only Thanks

Comment: Yes the powershell where command has a -contains operation but you wouldn't want to use it for dates.

So let's say you wanted to supply a given date to pull values from:  
  
    $startDate = '05-28-2014 00:00:00'  
    $endDate = '05-28-2014 23:59:59'  
  
    $MyList.Items | where {($_['Created'] -ge $startDate) -and ($_['Created'] -le $endDate)}  
  
Where -ge is _greater than or equal to_ and -le is _less than or equal to_.